# cannot run Robo 3T QT app

Tags: 16.04, qt5

I want to run [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) app. When I start it from shortcut it just keeps loading without showing the window. But if I run the binary from console, it gives me this error

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
[1]    4098 abort (core dumped)  ./robo3t
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, had same issue.

```
mkdir ~/robo-backup
mv robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++* ~/robo-backup/
robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t
```

Found this [here](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1384)

Comment: Hey that works! Been looking for that. Thanks for the response.